# Complex extension of the Stone - von Neumann Theorem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have two questions related to an extension of the [Stone - von Neumann Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups):

(1) Are there unitary groups with uncountably many elements indexed over the complex plane?

(2) Can the Stone - von Neumann Theorem be formulated over $\mathbb {C}$ instead of over $\mathbb {R}$, to establish a one-to-one correspondence between *self-adjoint operators on a Hilbert space* $\mathcal {H}$ and *one-parameter families of continuous unitary operators* $\{U_{z}\}_{z\in \mathbb {C}}$:

(1)$\forall z_{o}\in \mathbb {C} ,\ \psi \in {\mathcal {H}}:\ \lim _{z\to z_o}U_{z}(\psi )=U_{z_o}(\psi), $

(2)$\forall z_1,z_2\in \mathbb {C} :\ U_{z_1+z_2}=U_{z_1}U_{z_2}.$

I'm interested whether its possible to derive a one-to-one correspondence between a *(complex) parameter strongly continuous unitary groups of operators*
$U :\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}$ and *linear operators* (not necessarily self-adjoint/Hermitian!)
$A_U :\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}$ by

$$A_U\ \psi = \lim_{|z|\to 0}{\frac{U(z)\psi - \psi}{iz}}\\
U_A(z)=e^{izA}\ ,$$

where the *domain* of the operator $A$ is
$D(A) = \left \{\psi\in\mathcal{H}: \lim_{|z|\to 0}{\frac{U(z)\psi-\psi}{iz}}\ {\text{exists}}\right \}$.

And conversely, for any a given operator $A_o$, there exists a  (complex-indexed) strongly continuous unitary group $\{U_{A_o}(z)\}_{z\in\mathbb{C}}$, such that this relation
between the operator $A_o$ and the unitary group $U_{A_o}$ is satisfied on the domain of $A_o$.

Comment: That's *extremely* unlikely to work. The standard example fails to be unitary off the real axis. And your conditions are strong enough that the restriction to the real axis triggers the standard SvN theorem, and the holomorphism probably completely constrains the off-real behaviour to be the same as the standard case.

Comment: (but there are always subtleties and I could be proved wrong by folks who do mathematical physics for a living.)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: I'm actually thinking of polar-coordinate parametrization of the complex plane, $z=te^{i\theta}\in \mathbb{C}$, so that the magnitude of $|z|=t\in\mathbb{R}^+$ preserves the standard formulation, whereas the phase of the complex time (kime-phase) $\theta\in [-\pi,+\pi)$ does not alter the group unitarity condition. I hope this makes sense? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

(I do not understand well where the [Stone-Von Neumann Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem) enters the issue, maybe the right theorem is the [Stone Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups), not the SvN one?)

Suppose that a strongly continuous one-parameter group of unitaries $\mathbb{C} \ni z \mapsto U_z$ exists in the complex  Hilbert space $\cal H$ with the properties you described. In particular $A_U : D(A_U) \to {\cal H}$ exists with domain $D(A_U)\subset {\cal H}$ defined as you indicated.

Take $\phi \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\mathbb{R} \ni t \mapsto U_{e^{i\phi}t}$ is a strongly continuous one-parameter group of unitaries in standard sense and every $\psi\in D(A_U)$, per definition, belongs to the domain of its selfadjoint generator $A_\phi$ according to the Stone theorem. As a consequence, computing the $t$-derivative of both sides of
$$U_{e^{i\phi}t} \psi = e^{itA_\phi}\psi$$
we have
$$\tag{1} e^{i\phi}A_U\psi = A_\phi \psi\:, \quad \forall \psi \in D(A_U)\:.$$
In particular
$$e^{-i\phi'} \langle \psi, A_{\phi'}\psi\rangle = \langle \psi, A_U\psi \rangle =  e^{-i\phi}\langle \psi,A_\phi\psi\rangle \:.$$
In other words
$$\langle \psi, A_{\phi'}\psi\rangle = e^{i(\phi'-\phi)} \langle \psi, A_{\phi}\psi\rangle\:.$$
The two operators are selfadjoint and thus $\langle \psi, A_{\phi'}\psi\rangle, \langle \psi, A_{\phi}\psi\rangle \in \mathbb{R}$.
The found identity is therefore true only if $$\langle \psi, A_{\phi}\psi\rangle =0\:, \quad \forall \psi \in D(A_U)\:, \quad \forall \phi \in \mathbb{R}\:.$$
By polarization we also have
$$\langle \psi', A_{\phi}\psi\rangle =0\:, \quad \forall \psi, \psi' \in D(A_U)\:, \quad \forall \phi\in \mathbb{R}\:.$$
At this point (1) yields
$$\langle \psi', A_U\psi\rangle =0\:, \quad \forall \psi, \psi' \in D(A_U)\:, \quad \forall \phi \in \mathbb{R}\:.$$
If $D(A_U)$ is dense, this identity immediately proves that $A_U=0$.

I should check but I am very confident that the density property of $D(A_U)$ can be proved exactly as in the case of the proof of the standard Stone theorem (using the Garding vectors on the additive group $\mathbb{C}$).

With this *caveat* (but it is easy to check), the result is disappointing:  if a representation as the one you defined exists, the generator is always trivial $A_U=0$.  Standard properties of $C_0$ semigroups  imply that the representation $U$ itself is trivial as well: $U_z=I$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

I stress that the overall obstruction is the request that **all** $U_z$ of the group representation are **unitaries** if $z\in \mathbb{C}$.